# Particle System is not playing through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this method and tried some others as well but unable to play the particle system(i.e for bullet shells ).

```
public ParticleSystem particleSystem; 

void Start() {
    particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
}

void Update() {
    particleSystem.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not put your play triggers in the Update() of a MonoBehaviour because it will call play on every frame.

Try something like this instead:

```
public ParticleSystem particleSystem; 
private bool isPlaying = false;

void Start() {
    particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    particleSystem.Clear();    // Reset the particles
}

void Update() {
    if(!isPlaying) {
        particleSystem.Play();
        isPlaying = true;
    }
}
```

Using particleSystem.Clear() before calling particleSystem.Play() can also help with particle issues.

The easiest way to stop and play a particle system is to deactivate and activate the particle system game object. To do this, the controlling script must be placed in a parent or separate object.

Comment: still not working idk what's the problem i have the script and the particle system on the same gameobject  but still not playing.....it plays if i stimulate from the scene view but not playing through code

Comment: if i use play on awake it also plays but not playing through the code

Comment: Another way to reset your particles before playing is to deactivate it first. To do this, put your script on a parent object instead and let the script deactivate the particle system object to stop, activate to play.

Comment: yes this was the solution thanks ..........okay so after trouble of hours i found that the best way to manipulate the particle system i.e activate and detivate on your will is to create an empty gameobject assign the particle system you made to it and then on and off this gameobject exactly at which part in the code you want to by setActivce command. I hope it will help someone in someway

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure it's not already playing, or you will reset it

```cs
void Update() {
    if(!particleSystem.isPlaying) particleSystem.Play();
}
```

Comment: still not working idk what's the problem i have the script and the particle system on the same gameobject  but still not playing.....it plays if i stimulate from the scene view but not playing through code

Comment: if i use play on awake it also plays but not playing through the code

Comment: While the game is running, does the Unity inspector say that the particlesystem is playing?  Also, are any errors/exceptions printing to the log?

Comment: the problem is solved by putting it on a gameobject and by activiting and deactivating the gameobject but thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

okay so after trouble of hours i found that the best way to manipulate the particle system i.e activate and detivate on your will is to create an empty gameobject assign the particle system you made to it and then on and off this gameobject exactly at which part in the code you want to by setActivce command. I hope it will help someone in someway

Answer (score 0):

I found that the ParticleSystem component doesn't like being disabled and enabled, e.g. when being put into a pool and retrieved again.

After retrieving them from the pool and making their GameObject active, **calling .Play() or .Stop() just doesn't do anything**. I have to delay the call to .Play() (or .Stop() if using PlayOnAwake = true and I want it to start out being stopped) until next update, to ensure that the ParticleSystem actually gets set to the intended state, either using a coroutine or doing a continuous check in Update.